# Divergent sequence with convergent Cesaro means

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to come up with an example of a divergent sequence $(x_n)$ with convergent Cesaro means.

Cesaro means are the sequence $y_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_n$.

I am having a hard time even testing examples. For example, I was considering the sequence $\sqrt{n}$, but how would I check convergence if I don't know what the limit is? The book I'm reading has not gotten to criteria for convergence/divergence; all the tools I have are the definition of convergence, the Algebraic Limit Theorem and consequences.

Comment: $x_n=(-1)^n$ is the standard example.

Answer (score 0):

Let some values of $x_n$ be different, or even large, and the rest equal to zero. Make sure the nonzero values are infinitely many, but become less and less frequent. For example, $x_n = n$ if $n$ is a power of $2$, and $x_n = 0$ otherwise. Try to come up with a few more example of your own to make sure you understand what's going on.